# New to Java Programming, and trying to construct a Circle class with a tester main

Tags: java, class, testing, geometry

So I'm in a beginning Java class and our second assignment is to create a circle class with a tester, and my first file, which is the public class Circle, looks like this

```
public class Circle
{

    Circle ( ) { }

    int r;

    double area() {
        return Math.PI*r*r;
    }
    double diameter( ) 
    {
        return 2 * r;
    }

    double circumference( ) {
        return Math.PI * 2 * r;
    }

    int getR( ) {
        return r;
    }
}
```

This gave no compilation errors, so I thought I was hopefully on the right track. Then my Circle_test file gave some error I couldn't even spot.

```
Circle_test.java line 6: error: cannot find symbol

    c.setR(1);
     ^

Circle_test.java line 11: error: cannot find symbol

    c.setR(i)
     ^
```

---

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String [ ] args) {

        Circle c = new Circle( );

        c.setR(1);
        System.out.printf("a = %f\n", c.area( ));

        double a;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            c.setR(i);
            a = c.area( );
        }
    }
}
```

Any help regarding as to why I'm getting these errors would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You are missing setter method called `setR()` in Circle class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have a radius setter e.g.

```
public void setR(int r) {
   this.r = r;
}
```

You may prefer to initialise `r` via the constructor e.g.

```
public Circle(int r) {
   this.r = r;
}
```

such that you *can't* initialise a `Circle` without a radius. That a lot more reliable, and is a step towards making `Circle` an *immutable* class (meaning that it's unchangeable and thus more easily understandable)

Comment: Wow...I feel kind of dumb for not realizing that earlier. I thought I had everything set, especially since I thought I already had the c.setR so I thought I was good to go.

And luckily it did compile, but now it can't run for some reason, tells me it could not find or load main class Circle_test

Comment: Just a couple of notes.

1) Since your `r` field is an `int`, and uninitialized Java integers are actually set to 0, your empty constructor would build a circle with a radius of 0 - basically, a point.

2) It is generally a good idea to use stateless objects when possible. The suggestion of Brian about having a meaningful constructor makes me think of a second possible improvement: if you declare `final` your field, you will be forced by the compiler to create a meaningful constructor. On the other hand, you will lose the possibility to have a setter.

Answer (score 1):

You have to have a setter method for variable `r` in Circle class. Add the followinf method to `Circle` class

```
public void setR(int r) {
   this.r = r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't have `setR` method in your `Circle` class. Add this code in your `Circle` class

```
public void setR(int r) {
   this.r = r;
}
```

OR

```
public Circle(int r) {
   this.r = r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you have getter methods for integer field r "getR()", you did not implement a setter method for r.  "c.setR(1)" does not mean anything. You should implement a setR(int) method.

```
        public void setR(int r){
         this.r = r;
           }
```

should be fine